# Closest is undefined if table has two rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with button in every row.And I want get value closest button.It is good to get value of input if table have only one row,but if table have two row or multi row I get value is "undefined".I don't understand why ?I use jquery code as :

```
var barcodName=$(id).closest('tr').find('.name').attr('value');
alert(barcodeName.value);
```

This is a GUI of table.

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
   <input type='button' value='Save' onclick='saveValue(this);'/>
 </td>
 <td>
   <input type='text' class='name' />
 </td>
 <td>
   <input type='text' class='series' />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <input type='button' value='Save' onclick='saveValue(this);'/>
 </td>
 <td>
   <input type='text' class='name' />
 </td>
 <td>
   <input type='text' class='series' />
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `$(id)` I assume you do have an element with and `id` attribute? Also does the variable `id` have the `#` in it? Would be good to have the all HTML the code is actually targeting.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle demo with not working example.

Comment: And `barcodeName.value` will fail as `var barcodName=$(id).closest('tr').find('.name').attr('value');` will return a value not an object with a value property.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the inline onclick and use nonobstrusive jquery .on giving each button a class (for example saveButton)

Besides you can use jquery val() to get that value

So it would be something like this

```
$('.saveButton').on('click', function(){
    var barcodName=$(this).closest('tr').find('.name').val();
});
```

Yo can find a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5vgjmpma/). Note that i use console.log instead of alert for checking the value

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
      <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input  type='button' value='Save' onclick="saveValue(this);"  />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type='text' class='name' value="data1" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type='text' class='series' />
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input type='button' value='Save' onclick="saveValue(this);" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type='text' class='name' value="data2" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type='text' class='series' />
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Script:

```
    function saveValue(data) {
        var barcodName = $(data).closest('tr').find('.name').attr("value");
        alert(barcodName);
    }
```

hope this code will be useful.

Comment: What's the point of rewriting exactly the same as in my answer?

Comment: Hey sorry mitomed !! after added my comment only, i viewed you answer, actually my internet connection was slow, that's page rendering is not proper.. ok i delete my comment.. and your fiddle is not working.. pls check it out

Comment: Thanks @Jake745, I think my fiddle works only thing is I'm not alerting the result but writing it to the console with console.log